# CSS content behind Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: html, css, z-index

Is there a way to put CSS-div content over a embeded Adobe Acrobat Reader session?

I've tried with CSS z-index: -1; on the iframe Acrobat Reader launches in but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by overlaying the reader with an `<iframe>`, just as the approach with other plug-ins and `<select>` boxes. Also, setting the wmode parameter of the embed tag (if you are using one) to `transparent`. Not sure about the last one, but it works for Flash and Silverlight.

You can check a demo of the IFRAME approach (only under IE) at this [demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/functionality/overlay/defaultcs.aspx). (Sorry for the shameless plug, it's the first example that I think of)